# How to anti-transliterate Latin to Cyrillic?

Tags: c#, .net, transliteration

What will you do if you need to do reverse action? Here is solution. Sample: 
Kolkhoz Imeni Il’icha - Колхоз Имени Ильича

PS: Verified works with a geonames.org

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is function:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var str = "Kolkhoz Imeni Il’icha";

            Console.WriteLine(UnTrans1(str));
            Console.WriteLine(UnTrans2(str));

            var count = 1000000;

            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                UnTrans1(str);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                UnTrans2(str);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string UnTrans2(string str)
        {
            var sb = Pool<StringBuilder>.Get();

            if (sb == null)
            {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Clear();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                var itm = str[i];

                switch (itm)
                {
                        // lower
                    case 's':
                    {
                        if (i + 3 < str.Length)
                        {
                            if (str[i + 1] == 'h')
                            {
                                if (str[i + 2] == 'c' && str[i + 3] == 'h')
                                {
                                    sb.Append('щ');

                                    i += 3;

                                    break;
                                }

                                i += 1;

                                sb.Append('ч');

                                break;
                            }

                            sb.Append('с');

                            break;
                        }

                        if (i + 1 < str.Length)
                        {
                            if (str[i + 1] == 'h')
                            {
                                i += 1;

                                sb.Append('ч');

                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        sb.Append('с');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'y':
                    {
                        if (i + 1 < str.Length)
                        {
                            switch (str[i+1])
                            {
                                case 'a':
                                {
                                    i += 1;

                                    sb.Append('я');

                                    continue;
                                }
                                case 'e':
                                {
                                    i += 1;

                                    sb.Append('е');

                                    continue;
                                }
                                case 'u':
                                {
                                    i += 1;

                                    sb.Append('ю');

                                    continue;
                                }
                                case 'ë':
                                {
                                    i += 1;

                                    sb.Append('ё');

                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        sb.Append('ы');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'z':
                    {
                        if (i + 1 < str.Length && str[i + 1] == 'h')
                        {
                            i += 1;

                            sb.Append('ж');

                            break;
                        }

                        sb.Append('з');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'k':
                    {
                        if (i + 1 < str.Length && str[i + 1] == 'h')
                        {
                            i += 1;

                            sb.Append('х');

                            break;
                        }

                        sb.Append('к');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'i':
                    {
                        if (i + 1 < str.Length && str[i + 1] == 'y')
                        {
                            i += 1;

                            sb.Append('й');

                            break;
                        }

                        sb.Append('и');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'c':
                    {
                        if (i + 1 < str.Length && str[i + 1] == 'h')
                        {
                            i += 1;

                            sb.Append('ч');

                            break;
                        }

                        sb.Append('с');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'f':
                    {
                        sb.Append('ф');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'u':
                    {
                        sb.Append('у');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 't':
                    {
                        sb.Append('т');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'r':
                    {
                        sb.Append('р');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'p':
                    {
                        sb.Append('п');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'o':
                    {
                        sb.Append('о');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'n':
                    {
                        sb.Append('н');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'm':
                    {
                        sb.Append('м');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'l':
                    {
                        sb.Append('л');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'd':
                    {
                        sb.Append('д');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'g':
                    {
                        sb.Append('г');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'v':
                    {
                        sb.Append('в');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'b':
                    {
                        sb.Append('б');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'a':
                    {
                        sb.Append('а');

                        break;
                    }
                    case '’':
                    case '\'':
                    {
                        sb.Append('ь');

                        break;
                    }
                    case '”':
                    case '\"':
                    {
                        sb.Append('ъ');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'e':
                    {
                        sb.Append('e');

                        break;
                    }
                        // upper
                    case 'S':
                    {
                        if (i + 3 < str.Length)
                        {
                            if (str[i + 1] == 'h')
                            {
                                if (str[i + 2] == 'c' && str[i + 3] == 'h')
                                {
                                    i += 3;

                                    sb.Append('Щ');

                                    break;
                                }

                                i += 1;

                                sb.Append('Ч');

                                break;
                            }

                            sb.Append('С');

                            break;
                        }

                        if (i + 1 < str.Length)
                        {
                            if (str[i + 1] == 'h')
                            {
                                i += 1;

                                sb.Append('Ч');

                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        sb.Append('С');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'Y':
                    {
                        if (i + 1 < str.Length)
                        {
                            switch (str[i + 1])
                            {
                                case 'a':
                                    {
                                        i += 1;

                                        sb.Append('Я');

                                        continue;
                                    }
                                case 'e':
                                    {
                                        i += 1;

                                        sb.Append('Е');

                                        continue;
                                    }
                                case 'u':
                                    {
                                        i += 1;

                                        sb.Append('Ю');

                                        continue;
                                    }
                                case 'ë':
                                    {
                                        i += 1;

                                        sb.Append('Ё');

                                        continue;
                                    }
                            }
                        }

                        sb.Append('Ы');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'Z':
                    {
                        if (i + 1 < str.Length && str[i + 1] == 'h')
                        {
                            i += 1;

                            sb.Append('Ж');

                            break;
                        }

                        sb.Append('З');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'K':
                    {
                        if (i + 1 < str.Length && str[i + 1] == 'h')
                        {
                            i += 1;

                            sb.Append('Х');

                            break;
                        }

                        sb.Append('К');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'I':
                    {
                        if (i + 1 < str.Length && str[i + 1] == 'y')
                        {
                            i += 1;

                            sb.Append('Й');

                            break;
                        }

                        sb.Append('И');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'C':
                    {
                        if (i + 1 < str.Length && str[i + 1] == 'h')
                        {
                            i += 1;

                            sb.Append('Ч');

                            break;
                        }

                        sb.Append('С');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'F':
                    {
                        sb.Append('Ф');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'U':
                    {
                        sb.Append('У');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'T':
                    {
                        sb.Append('Т');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'R':
                    {
                        sb.Append('Р');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'P':
                    {
                        sb.Append('Н');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'O':
                    {
                        sb.Append('О');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'N':
                    {
                        sb.Append('Н');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'M':
                    {
                        sb.Append('М');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'L':
                    {
                        sb.Append('Л');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'D':
                    {
                        sb.Append('Д');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'G':
                    {
                        sb.Append('Г');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'V':
                    {
                        sb.Append('В');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'B':
                    {
                        sb.Append('Б');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'A':
                    {
                        sb.Append('А');

                        break;
                    }
                    case 'E':
                    {
                        sb.Append('Э');

                        break;
                    }
                    default :
                    {
                        sb.Append(itm);

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            Pool<StringBuilder>.Release(sb);

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        static string UnTrans1(string str)
        {
            return str.Replace("shch", "щ")//
                      .Replace("Shch", "Щ")//
                      .Replace("ya", "я")//
                      .Replace("Ya", "Я")//
                      .Replace("zh", "ж")//
                      .Replace("Zh", "Ж")//
                      .Replace("Ye", "Е")//
                      .Replace("ye", "е")//
                      .Replace("yu", "ю")//
                      .Replace("Yu", "Ю")//
                      .Replace("Sh", "Ш")//
                      .Replace("sh", "ш")//
                      .Replace("kh", "х")//
                      .Replace("Kh", "Х")//
                      .Replace("iy", "й")//
                      .Replace("Iy", "Й")//
                      .Replace("Yë", "Ё")//
                      .Replace("yë", "ё")//
                      .Replace("Ch", "Ч")//
                      .Replace("ch", "ч")//
                      .Replace("F", "Ф")//
                      .Replace("f", "ф")//
                      .Replace("u", "у")//
                      .Replace("U", "У")//
                      .Replace("T", "Т")
                      .Replace("t", "т")
                      .Replace("S", "С")//
                      .Replace("s", "с")//
                      .Replace("R", "Р")
                      .Replace("r", "р")
                      .Replace("P", "П")
                      .Replace("p", "п")
                      .Replace("O", "О")
                      .Replace("o", "о")
                      .Replace("N", "Н")
                      .Replace("n", "н")
                      .Replace("M", "М")
                      .Replace("m", "м")
                      .Replace("L", "Л")
                      .Replace("l", "л")
                      .Replace("K", "К")//
                      .Replace("k", "к")//
                      .Replace("I", "И")//
                      .Replace("i", "и")//
                      .Replace("Z", "З")//
                      .Replace("z", "з")//
                      .Replace("D", "Д")
                      .Replace("d", "д")
                      .Replace("G", "Г")
                      .Replace("g", "г")
                      .Replace("V", "В")
                      .Replace("v", "в")
                      .Replace("B", "Б")
                      .Replace("b", "б")
                      .Replace("A", "А")
                      .Replace("a", "а")
                      .Replace("’", "ь")
                      .Replace("”", "ъ")
                      .Replace("\"", "ъ")
                      .Replace("Y", "Ы")//
                      .Replace("y", "ы")//
                      .Replace("'", "ь")
                      .Replace("E", "Э")
                      .Replace("e", "е");
        }
    }

    public static class Pool<T> where T : class
    {
        static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<Type, Queue<T>>> ht;
        static ValueLock locker;

        static Pool()
        {
            ht = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<Type, Queue<T>>>(256);
            locker = new ValueLock();
        }

        public static T Get()
        {
            var idt = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            Dictionary<Type, Queue<T>> dic;

            if (!ht.ContainsKey(idt))
            {
                dic = new Dictionary<Type, Queue<T>>();

                locker.Lock();

                ht.Add(idt, dic);

                locker.Unlock();
            }
            else
            {
                dic = ht[idt];
            }

            T obj = null;

            if (dic.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            {
                var q = dic[typeof(T)];

                if (q.Count > 0)
                {
                    obj = q.Dequeue();
                }
            }

            return obj;
        }

        public static void Release(T obj)
        {
            var idt = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            Dictionary<Type, Queue<T>> dic;

            if (!ht.ContainsKey(idt))
            {
                dic = new Dictionary<Type, Queue<T>>();

                locker.Lock();

                ht.Add(idt, dic);

                locker.Unlock();
            }
            else
            {
                dic = ht[idt];
            }

            Queue<T> q;

            if (dic.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            {
                q = dic[typeof(T)];
            }
            else
            {
                q = new Queue<T>();

                dic.Add(typeof(T), q);
            }

            q.Enqueue(obj);
        }
    }

    public class ValueLock
    {
        const long maxTime = 100;
        int val;
        long time;

        public ValueLock()
        {
            val = 0;
            time = 0;
        }

        public void Lock()
        {
            var cur = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            if (cur == val)
            {
                return;
            }

            while (true)
            {
                if (val == 0)
                {
                    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref val, cur, 0) == 0)
                    {
                        time = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

                        return;
                    }
                }

                if ((DateTime.Now.Ticks - time) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond > maxTime)
                {
                    var tmp = val;

                    // unlock
                    if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref val, cur, tmp) == tmp)
                    {
                        time = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

                        return;
                    }
                }

                Thread.Yield();
            }
        }

        public void Unlock()
        {
            val = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd say idea is correct, but implementation is weird =P

Comment: Understandable implementation will do more "quality" solution depending on the task ...

Comment: You could simply copy translating table (to example, from [here](http://mainspy.ru/translit_perevodchik)) instead of that `.Replace`. You are right, it doesn't distract, but that's possibly a reason of downvote and reason why I myself don't upvote =P

Comment: @Sinatr where you are?

Comment: Sneaking in darkness as always. Why do you need me?

Comment: @Sinatr I added another algorithm at your request. I want to hear that you love me :).

Comment: Case-algorithm will crash if you have `"s"` at the end (you don't check array bounds). Both algorithms should work register-careless (you can convert to lower-case when processing and then back to upper-case if it was, currently both algorithm will not proceed `"SHCH"` properly). Both are [*WET*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). Instead of having a lot of code preferred way is organize data in proper data structure and use short code (use array and loop with `Replace` instead of multiple `Replace`). Question is useful for others russian programmers,but answer needs work =P

Comment: @Sinatr The method of which you speak is not as fast as what I did. Why do the extra conversion, if they can not do? And going beyond the bounds of the array are you joked, everything is fine, or give a string which will exception.

Comment: I overlooked `if`, sorry. Case-algorithm is better performance wise (single pass), still, coding is wet. Nesting could be defined with proper data structure (tree to example), notice how repeatable code is. You can try [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you want to hear more opinions.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use a dictionary?